# PHP PDO Possible LEFT JOIN get column names and column value

Tags: php, pdo, left-join

I have two Tables:

1. users

   Standard user table (id, name, email, country, city, password, gender).
2. languages

   Every column has the name of a language e.g. "english", "spanish", "russian".
   The value of any column is an int, which indicates the level of proficiency in the corresponding language.

The id for every row is taken out of the user table `user.id` to save the languages of a user. standard entry is `NULL` and will be replaced by an int if a language is spoken by a user.

I want to select all users that fit the entry of a search query (country, city, gender), then i want to check the language table by user id taken from the user table `LEFT JOIN languages ON (user.id=languages.id)` and get back only the column name and values of the columns that don't contain `NULL`.

My approach so far:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . self::TABLE . 
      ' WHERE country=? AND city LIKE ? AND gender LIKE ? LEFT JOIN languages ON ('.  
       self::TABLE .
      '.id=languages.id) SHOW COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN NAME ? ORDER BY name DESC';
```

The above code is obviously faulty, my question is, how would i go about it after SHOW COLUMNS?

Sample records:
language table
user_id = 9, english = NULL, spanish = 3, russian = 2, Korean = 1

user table
id = 9, email = me@me.com, country = South Korea, city = Seoul, gender = 1

After i select only the users that fit the country, city and gender provided by the search query, i want to take each users id and check the language table for the columns that contain not null and add those column names along with their value to the user object for each user seperately, then return all objects, so i can output them to the logged in user who is doing the search.

How i INSERT and UPDATE the languages:

```
public function updateLanguages($languages, $id) {

    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM " . self::TABLE . " WHERE user_id=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    $userId = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if (empty($userId)) {

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . self::TABLE . ' (user_id) VALUES(?)';
        $values = array($id);
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($values);

        $this->resetLanguages($id);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($languages) / 2; $i++) {

            $sql = 'UPDATE ' . self::TABLE . ' SET ' . $languages['language' . $i] . '=? WHERE user_id =? LIMIT 1';
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array($languages['langlevel' . $i], $id));
            $stmt = null;
        }
    } else {

        $this->resetLanguages($id);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($languages) / 2; $i++) {

            $sql = 'UPDATE ' . self::TABLE . ' SET ' . $languages['language' . $i] . '=? WHERE user_id =? LIMIT 1';
            $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array($languages['langlevel' . $i], $id));
            $stmt = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Reset function:

```
public function resetLanguages($id) {
    $languages = new Languages();
    $allLangs = $this->getLanguages();
    $allLangs = array_slice($allLangs, 1, 137);

    foreach ($allLangs as $lang) {

        $sql = 'UPDATE ' . self::TABLE . ' SET ' . $lang['Field'] . '=? WHERE user_id =? LIMIT 1';
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(null, $id));
        $stmt = null;
    }
}
```

User INSERT:

```
public function save($data) {
    $utilityManager = new UtilityManager();
    $rand = $utilityManager->randomGen();
    $user = new User();
    $user->arrayToObject($data);
    $folderName = $user->getName() . $rand;
    $profileFolder = 'profilePic';
    mkdir('users/' . $folderName, 0755);
    mkdir("users/$folderName/" . $profileFolder, 0755);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . self::TABLE . ' (name, email, country, password, emailConfirm, imageFolder, registered, lastOnline) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), NOW())';
    $values = array($user->getName(), $user->getEmail(), $user->getCountry(), $user->getPassword(), $user->getEmailConfirm(), $folderName);
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql); // prepares the sql statement to be filled
    $stmt->execute($values); //fills the sql statement with the $values array

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $utilityManager->sendEmail(array('reg', $user->getEmail(), $user->getName(), $user->getEmailConfirm()));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give sample records and expected results?

Comment: You cannot retrieve SQL column name. But you can do workaround in form of setting the column comnent to same valuje as column name and retrieve that in your query instead

Comment: your database design is wrong. languages table should have only two columns: user_id and language_id. in this case the query will be a piece of cake.

Comment: @JohnWoo i added sample records for both tables.

Comment: I can't understand your question it seems has lots of lecture mistakes or i can't made it. Any way please describe your problem clearly using an example.

Comment: @MohammadSalehSalehi i have updated the post with an exact description of what i want to do.

Comment: so please add your desired result as an example to help.

Comment: most of users also add table data sample to clear the problem.

Comment: @RyanVincent added the functions from my managers.

Answer (score -1):

Your database design is wrong. languages table should have only two columns: user_id and language_id

In this case you can simply join users table to language table

```
SELECT * FROM users u, languages l  
    WHERE u.id = user_id AND lang_id=? AND country=? AND city LIKE ? AND gender LIKE ?
```

Note that with proper structure you will get a lot of advantages. For example, instead of having just "yes" or "no" for the language, you can add "proficiency" field, to mark different gradations. And then select all the users whose proficiency in the selected language is no less than given one.